# Need help regarding the Blaz meter recording

Tags: jmeter, recording, blazemeter

I am new to jmeter script.
I am Recording a script using Blaze meter Chrome recording extension. I am currently recording my step.After Recording Some steps Blaze meter recording popup get hanged.I also click on the extension icon it's showing that start record again.pls help me.
[snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQLax.png)
Tech people I am wating for your response.
Thnaks

Solution required
pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

[BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) can only record [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).

If the action in UI (i.e. sorting) doesn't result in a HTTP request - it will not be recorded. If it uses another [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) - it will not be recorded as well, you will have to capture the request using a sniffer tool and choose an appropriate JMeter [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which supports this protocol and configure it accordingly.

I would recommend opening your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and see what's going on in "Network" tab, if there is no network request associated with the action in the UI - you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Please give me an idea with example..